# How to limit the selection of Tab Bar items?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am using tab bar controller and i want to check which tab user has selected and before loading the selected tab view and i want to show user an Alert about login. Currently using this method

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{

    if (self.selectedViewController == [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"You are not logged in. Do you want to log in?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Log In", nil];

        [alert show];
    }

}
```

but view is loaded with an alert. 
any help would be highly appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any custom class for your `UITabBarController`? you can achieve this using the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method `
- tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`. Compare your controller with the selected viewController and perform the action.

Comment: @Vijay Masiwal - i 've implemented the delegate of tabBarController as you are saying and implemented this method also but this method does not get called when i put break point on method.

Comment: Have you check that other delegate methods get called? I think you have not properly set the delegate of your tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method. It will validate selecting viewcontroller you have selected. 
So you can check that, viewcontroller should select or not and return BOOL value.

```
     - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
     shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController   {
     }
```

Comment: @Sameer :- i 've just implemented this method and put a break point. but this method is not called.

Comment: You mean tabBar:didSelectItem: method is being called and shouldSelectViewController: is not?
Have you set the delegate ?

Comment: Opps sorry, Its Tabbar, I have written for TabbarController. Let me look at it.

Comment: Do you have object of UITabbarController ? b'cos using UITabbar there is no delegate method. And you can disable it to prevent loading view of that tab. But in this case you will not get UIAlert message

Comment: `self.parentViewController.tabBarController` using this we can approach the tabBarController. But login Alert is mandatory in my requirments..

Comment: okay, then you can create custom class of TabbarController set to your tabbarcontoller. and in That custom class you can handle delegate methods of Tabbarcontroller. Else you can set delegate of Tabbarcontroller in your baseclass where it initialize or Tabbarcontroller always accessible. Delegate method shouldSelectViewController: will be accessible once you set delegate of current object of Tabbarcontroller.

Comment: @Sameer I ended up my work making a class with a custom view in footer and having buttons in it. And changing root view controller in button actions method. Thanks a lot for your suggestions and time.